# Durupal 7でテンプレートコーディングを楽にする方法はありますか？

Tags: cms, drupal

Drupal 7が出力するHTMLの階層が深く見通しが悪いのですが、良いテーマやモジュールはありますか？

Comment: Qiitaの記事をQA形式に書き換えて再投稿する意味が分かりません　http://qiita.com/snize/items/5cde3daf90624c095fe4

Answer (score 0):

深い入れ子構造や、出力されるHTMLタグをテンプレートのPHPを修正せずに制御できる以下のような有用なテーマ・モジュールがあります。

- [mothership | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/mothership)
- [Clean Markup | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/clean_markup)

使ってないけど、[Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences)というモジュールもあります。

## テーマ：Mothership

Mothershipは他の多くのテーマとは違い、導入すれば見た目が整うものではなく余分なdivタグの入れ子やクラス名などを取り除いてくれるテーマです。なのでこのテーマ自体をカスタマイズするのではなく子テーマとして目的のビジュアルを作り上げて行くことを強くおすすめします。そのほか、開発に役立つオプションや設定が豊富なので[ドキュメント](https://www.drupal.org/node/1536448)に目を通しておくと良いです。

### 見てみようテーマ別階層の深さの変化

#### Bartikの場合

[image: Bartikの場合]

#### Mothershipの場合

[image: Mothershipの場合]

## モジュール：Clean Markup

Clean MarkupはPanelsとBlocksへクリーンなテンプレートを提供します。同時にオプションにより、任意のクラス名を指定したりラッパーを指定したりすることが可能です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]